# aws ses email sending limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

AWS ses in my account has production access. I have also setup automation for pausing domain/email addresses if bounce/complaint rate is high. I am looking to limit emails sending per domain. I mean any domain/email address in my account will be allowed to send only 100 emails per day. can someone please suggest me how can I do this? I have looked at various AWS docs but couldn't come up with any solution.